# microsoft azure smtp email relay setup

Tags: asp.net, azure, smtp, windows-server-2012

We are migrating from a dedicated server with a local virtual SMTP server to Windows Azure. As far as I can tell Windows Azure does not allow a local SMTP server to be setup in IIS. The SMTP Server option in the management console is missing. How would I setup an email relay so that I can have a .net web application send emails from a Windows Server 2012 virtual machine in Azure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is more like corollary to what @mcollier has stated. Given that you are already on Azure and you get 25,000 free emails (there are higher plans as well) with your subscription as well.

You can configure a `Virtual SMTP server` which relays to the sendgrid services. For the development perspective you will have the view of using your own SMTP server / service. Setting up a sendgrid based service is [explained in this link](http://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Mail_Servers/iis75.html).

I have used sendgrid earlier and my experience with this was amazing. As @mcollier has pointed out, using services like Sendgrid will give good chance of staying away from spam problem, if you try to setup and use the SMTP service of your own because of the reverse lookup etc.

**PS:** The above Virtual SMTP Server can be replaced with Amazon SES, which is equivalently a good service. Check out more [info here](http://sesblog.amazon.com/post/TxAXMJU3AAN5JA/Using-IIS-SMTP-on-Windows-2008-2012-with-Amazon-SES).

Comment: Just to be fair, Sendgrid is nice, but some alternatives exist. You should look at Mailjet for [Azure for instance](https://www.mailjet.com/azure?utm_source=Partners&utm_medium=Referral&utm_campaign=AzurePromotion). (Disclaimer, I work for them).

Answer (score 3):

First, assuming you're using a Windows Azure IaaS VM.  Correct?  If so, I *think* you need to enable that role/feature in Windows Server.

Second, why the *need* to send emails from that specific server?  Would a service like SendGrid work? One problem people sometimes have with email servers in Windows Azure is the domain of your service (something.cloudapp.net) does not match your vanity domain when a reverse DNS lookup is performed.  This could cause the email to be flagged as spam (since you don't technically own the sending domain, something.cloudapp.net).

Comment: Yes we are using a Windows Azure VM. The Management Console in the Azure virtual machine does not have the option to enable an SMTP Server. Since our previous setup was a local SMTP server we are not familiar with setting up a relay which is what seems to be required for Azure.

Is there any good sources/tutorials for setting up a relay through SendGrid, Amazon Simple Email, or some other service?

Comment: I just did a quick Bing search for installing SMTP on Windows 2012 - have a look at http://blog.powerbiz.net.au/exchange/how-to-set-up-an-internal-smtp-service-for-windows-server-2012-essentials/.

Comment: Also, have a look at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/store/service/?id=f131eadb-7aa3-401a-a2fb-1c7e71f45c3c for info on setting up SendGrid.  There is a free plan available for Windows Azure customers.  Personally, I'd go with a service like SendGrid (if it meets your requirements) - less to manage is a win.  :)

Comment: If you deployed a Windows Server 2012 or 2012 R2 then this is logical, SMTP and related tools are deprecated in that windows version , although the functionality is still available. check this Technet article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831568.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I developed an direct relay application using the normal RFC email commands and lock that on my application, but strange that some test emails get delivered using the relay on windows AZURE VM, and all other mails are not getting any bounce response, and making a sense that every email is being delivering,

This is strange behaviour on azure vm.

so it means you can't send email using azure vm as a smtp mail server, if like to test then simply download promailer marketing manager from [jsmtp.com](http://jsmtp.com)